# Is there another way to find a specific string in a database and obtain those results that match besides using the regular method?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to store the average ratings for various locations, but I need a way to find a specific string in a database and obtain those results that match the string other than the following method.  Any help would be appreciated,

Jacob

Current method that I can't use (see my other posts):

```
query.whereContains("reviewName", titleRev);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
```

Comment: To make this a complete question: why can't you use whereContains?

Comment: @danh sorry, I should've made this more clear but I need to set the rating of a rating bar in a different view, and I can't do that effectively with this method

Comment: Do you mean that some aspect of another view depends on the result of the query?

Comment: @danh yes to be more specific I want to add the results of a query to a list, and then take the average of the list. I then want to set the ratingbar's rating (inside of the info window for a google maps marker, which is just a different view) as the average of that list.

Comment: Okay.  That makes sense.  But what part are you having trouble with?  The code so far looks like it will find records (I'm guessing reviews) where the reviewName (I'm guessing the name of the thing being reviewed) contains a substring titleRev.  What about that isn't working?

Comment: @danh to put it simply, whenever I try to set the rating of the ratingbar inside of the infowindow from the query.findInBackground, nothing happens, no errors or anything

Comment: Okay.  The code posted so far looks like it should work.  We need to see more.  When its working, find will find the records you need, you will calculate an average from the results, then use that average to update a view (rating bar).  We need to figure out which part isn't working, and the only way I can think to do that is review the code.  If you log some debug info along the way, post the results of that, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78954/discussion-between-jacob-platin-and-danh).